# How to display color swatches for each product on the page of all products in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a block on the main page where I display all the products
I need to make sure that colors swatches and size options are displayed for each product. Can this be done standardly without plugins?
I displayed it as on the product page using product-variant-picker, but now I have an error in the console on my page, as I understand it, this option is not intended for multiple output on one page

```js
//variant picker

{%- unless product.has_only_default_variant -%}
  <variant-radios
    id="variant-radios-{{ section.id }}"
    class="no-js-hidden"
    data-section="{{ section.id }}"
    data-url="{{ product.url }}"
    {% if update_url == false %}
      data-update-url="false"
    {% endif %}
  >
    {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
      <fieldset class="js product-form__input">
        {% render 'custom-product-variant-options', product: product, option: option %}
      </fieldset>
    {%- endfor -%}
    <script type="application/json">
      {{ product.variants | json }}
    </script>
  </variant-radios>
{%- endunless -%}

//product card

<li>
....

 <div class="variants-picker__list">
        {% render 'product-variant-picker', product: product, product_form_id: product_form_id %}
      </div>

<li>
```

[An example of how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJQMA.png)